# Colon Usage in this sentence

Tags: grammar, colons

Is the colon used in this sentence correct?

**“The Dark Wood” is the vivid representation of a cloudy, misty forethought: in Dante’s Divine Comedy the ominous wood is a place for lost souls, who lose their way in life.**

Comment: Punctuation is a matter of style, so "correct" an "incorrect" don't apply as much as "conforming" and "noncomforming" to your style guide. Type "colon" into the "Search Q&A" box above to wade through the numerous answers. You'll find that colons are recommended to introduce conclusions from, examples for, or evidence to support the preceding clause. I find it hard to see how a place for lost souls fits into these categories for "misty forethought".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, this is stylistic.  However, in both APA and MLA, this would not be correct usage.  In MLA, a semicolon would be applicable.